# Display list items on top of each other

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm aiming to move through list items, fading one out as the other fades in. I need all three of these list items to display on the same line, on top of each other.  Should work with images of varying widths, the only common attribute may be the top position, relative to the div it is in.

[Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/6fs6GCh03fT2iLqhl8xp?p=preview)

```
.container {
  display:table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul {
  list-style-type:none;
}
```

To explain a little better, I need these items, whether it's text, images, divs of varying sizes to be in the middle of the screen, perfectly centered.

This is achievable with a javascript solution, by measuring the size of the element contained and subtracting the middle offset from the left side of the image.

What I'd like to achieve is a CSS3/HTML5 only option to this similar effect.

Comment: check my answer again. whatever you have inside the list item will always be centered

Comment: I updated with two images (same image varying sizes, and it displays the issue I'm having with answer). http://plnkr.co/edit/L8tsnopS9QvC4OteyIKQ?p=preview. These images middle points should be in the middle of whatever element they are in. For example, the middle of the small image, should be the middle of the big image in this example, and those are the only things they will have in common.

Comment: Check what I've done here http://jsfiddle.net/nsLq3ooc/1/

Comment: I can't see the big image. Only a portion of it.

Comment: Bevause the umage is bigger than the defined dimensions. See thishttp://jsfiddle.net/nsLq3ooc/2/

Comment: Please update your answer @SleekGeek

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question: Simply using position property value of absolute, will stack them on each other. Try this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0 auto;
  }

.container {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 70px;
  }


ul {
  list-style-type:none;
}

ul li {
    position: absolute;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

**Note:** You can use **z-index** to alter the order of the stack of the element.

Comment: Similar to the plunkr, I really want the variable width items to be centered on the containing div.  I updated the question with a little more specific guidance and an explanation of the javascript variant, of which I don't want to use. (edit: added more info)

Comment: OK. A litle bit of CSS will do that. Use the let property value to do that.

Comment: So the content div and text is a little off to the right, and I really need inside content to dynamicly determine the width.  Regardless of the width of the li element, it will be centered. Imagine the 1st element in your example being the widest, the second being second widest, and third being the least wide. You should see the outside of one, outside of two and entirety of three.  I'll update and add a picture

Comment: It is actually centered properly, it is just how the snippet renders it. It centers no matter the width and . add the picture and lets see.

Comment: See [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/L8tsnopS9QvC4OteyIKQ?p=preview) I added 2 images to the above (same image, different sizes).