# Stack images in unordered list on top of each other.

Tags: html, css

Thanks in advance for any insight any of you provide. I'm not finding the exact answer that I need.

[I have two rows of images but want one atop the other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFffn.jpg)

I tried this: 
[Display list items on top of each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583114/display-list-items-on-top-of-each-other)

but it doesn't seem to fix my problem.

Here's my HTML/CSS:

```
 <ul class="north-showcase">
                <li>
                    <figure class="before">
                        <img src="resources/img/170Northwoods/Bath.jpg" alt="Bathroom">
                    </figure>
                    <figure class="after">
                        <img src="resources/img/170Northwoods/WholeHouse.jpg" alt="Bathroom">
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure class="before">
                        <img src="resources/img/170Northwoods/Bath2.jpg" alt="Second Bathroom">
                    </figure>
                    <figure class="after">
                        <img src="resources/img/170Northwoods/Kitchen.jpg" alt="Second Bathroom">
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure class="before">
                        <img src="resources/img/170Northwoods/Kitchen.jpg" alt="">
                    </figure>
                    <figure class="after">
                        <img src="resources/img/170Northwoods/Bath2.jpg" alt="">
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure class="before">
                        <img src="resources/img/170Northwoods/WholeHouse.jpg" alt="">
                    </figure>
                    <figure class="after">
                        <img src="resources/img/170Northwoods/Bath.jpg" alt="">
                    </figure>
                </li>


            </ul>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.north-showcase {
list-style: none;
width: 100%;

}

.north-showcase li {
display: block;
float: left;
width: 25%;    
}

.before {
width: 100%;
margin: 0%;
z-index: 1;

}

.before img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;


}

.after {
width: 100%;
margin: 0%;
z-index: 2;

}

.after img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;


}
```

Comment: Do you want the photos to stack on top of each other with just 1 photo per row, or do you 2 photos side-by-side in each row and stacked?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response and thank you for any insight you an provide. Currently there are two rows, one above the other. I want there to be one row with 8 images one row of four below and another row of 4 a top that row. What I'm trying to accomplish is when you hover over the image it will fade into the image below. I've managed to figure out the fade part but I can't get the images to stack atop each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create an `.img-wrapper` div to contain the top and bottom pictures for each list item

```
<li>
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <figure class="before">
      <img src="resources/img/170Northwoods/Bath.jpg" alt="Bathroom">
    </figure>
    <figure class="after">
      <img src="resources/img/170Northwoods/WholeHouse.jpg" alt="Bathroom">
    </figure>
  </div>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.after, .before {
  position: absolute;
}
.north-showcase li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24%;
}
```

working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/kkdaily/6cwh3rkL/

NOTE: the `display: inline-block` property is causing extra spacing to appear between the list items. There are hacky solutions for this which include removing the end `</li>` tags. More info here: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Thank you for going through the effort of writing that all out and testing it. I also appreciate the additional trouble shooting info you provided. I'll try it out once I get home but it looks like you've solved my problem.

Comment: I actually had to try something else. I tried removing the spaces between the <li> tags as instructed but that didn't do it for me. I simply added margin:0 to the .after, .before classes and that worked for me. Thanks again!